# How to set up forward/inverse searches with AUCTeX and Zathura

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

I haven't been able to find much on how to set up Zathura to work with AUCTeX/Emacs in terms of forward/inverse-searching.  Has anyone been successful in this?

Comment: Thanks to [these instructions](https://wiki.math.cmu.edu/iki/wiki/tips/20140310-zathura-fsearch.html) I managed to open the viewer and activate forward/inverse search.  The problem is that you have first to open the viewer with the `-s` (to enable SyncTeX) and `-x` (to specify the editor) switches and **then** re-run `zathura` with `--synctex-forward`.  This isn't really comfortable.

Comment: @giordano: yes, I had seen those instructions, but they seem to be for vim, and I wasn't 100% certain how to adapt them to emacs.

I also found this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Emacs#SyncTeX_support   - but, again, it requires adapting - to AUCTeX rather than the built-in emacs TeX support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Zathura SyncTeX interface has recently changed (I'm using v0.3.2 at time of writing): there is now no `-s` flag to activate SyncTeX. It might be the case that SyncTeX is active all the time.

The SyncTeX support is complicated by two annoying quirks of Zathura:

1. Zathura doesn't accept `--synctex-forward` if the file is not already open.
2. The Zathura window doesn't steal focus when receiving a `--synctex-forward`.

My Emacs/AUCTeX setup is therefore the following:

- I am running an Emacs server such that `emacsclient` takes care of finding my frame and file.
- Add the following to your .emacs to let AUCTeX know you want to call
  `zathura-forward-search` for opening compiled pdfs:

```lisp
    (TeX-source-correlate-mode)        ; activate forward/reverse search
    (TeX-PDF-mode)
    (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list '("zathura" zathura-forward-search))
    (setq TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "zathura") (output-dvi "xdvi"))))
```

- The function `zathura-forward-search` is complicated: it takes care of which
  Zathura processes have been opened by Emacs and are still alive, and which are
  therefore safe to send `--synctex-forward` directives to. Otherwise, it spawns
  a new Zathura process for the file. Furthermore, it uses the small tool
  [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) to give focus to the Zathura window afterwards. This should be
  installed on the machine and in the path for that line to work.

  ```lisp
  (setq zathura-procs ())
  (defun zathura-forward-search ()
    ;; Open the compiled pdf in Zathura with synctex. This is complicated since
    ;; 1) Zathura refuses to acknowledge Synctex directive if the pdf is not
    ;; already opened
    ;; 2) This means we have to bookkeep open Zathura processes ourselves: first
    ;; open a new pdf from the beginning, if it is not already open. Then call
    ;; Zathura again with the synctex directive.
    (interactive)
    (let* ((zathura-launch-buf (get-buffer-create "*Zathura Output*"))
           (pdfname (TeX-master-file "pdf"))
           (zatentry (assoc pdfname zathura-procs))
           (zatproc (if (and zatentry (process-live-p (cdr zatentry)))
                        (cdr zatentry)
                      (progn
                        (let ((proc (progn (message "Launching Zathura")
                                           (start-process "zathura-launch"
                                                          zathura-launch-buf "zathura"
                                                           "-x" "emacsclient +%{line} %{input}" pdfname))))
                          (when zatentry
                            (setq zathura-procs (delq zatentry zathura-procs)))
                          (add-to-list 'zathura-procs (cons pdfname proc))
                          (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil)
                          proc))))
           (pid (process-id zatproc))
           (synctex (format "%s:0:%s"
                            (TeX-current-line)
                            (TeX-current-file-name-master-relative)))
           )
      (start-process "zathura-synctex" zathura-launch-buf "zathura" "--synctex-forward" synctex pdfname)
      (start-process "raise-zathura-wmctrl" zathura-launch-buf "wmctrl" "-a" pdfname)
      ))
  ```

  Errors from the launched processes will be printed in the created buffer `*Zathura Output*`.

  The `wmctrl` call might fail to raise the correct window if more than one window has the name of the pdf in its title.

Comment: Nice! I improved formatting and simplified the determination of `pdfname` `;-)`.

Answer (score 6):

A few of months ago, Zathura was updated so that calling `--synctex-forward` will open the file if it isn't already open.  As a result, the answer by @jsrn actually opens two instances of Zathura and the alternative is now much simpler.

Adding this to your emacs config or `'TeX-mode-hook` should work if you have `v11.89.1` or earlier:

```el
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
             '("Zathura"
               ("zathura "
                (mode-io-correlate " --synctex-forward %n:0:%b -x \"emacsclient +%{line} %{input}\" ")
                " %o")
               "zathura"))
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
             '(output-pdf "Zathura"))
```

Once [Giordano's change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=16f3dd415aa0ef1c870f9724dda9f895f2467133) makes it into the next release of AUCTeX, then the you will only need to add Zathura to the view program selection:

```el
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
             '(output-pdf "Zathura"))
```

Comment: Now Zathura is among AUCTeX [default viewers](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=16f3dd415aa0ef1c870f9724dda9f895f2467133), thanks for sharing the news!

Comment: I tried all three listed possibilities but none of them worked for me. Can you help me out? @giordano

Comment: @TimHilt please write to AUCTeX's mailing list at auctex@gnu.org ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Zathura+AUCTeX's forward search is almost perfect, but one thing is missing: Zathura's window is not automatically raised. Here's a hacky solution which monitors DBus messages and uses `xdotool` and `wmctrl` (yes, both) to raise the window.

`~/bin/zathura-raise.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-monitor --profile  "type='method_call', path='/org/pwmt/zathura',member=SynctexView" | sed -Eune '/zathura/{s/^.*PID-([0-9]+).*$/\1/;p}' | xargs -L 1 xdotool search --pid | sed -Eune '2~2p' | xargs -L 1 wmctrl -iR
```

While you can run `zathura-raise.sh` manually, here's a `systemd` service file, `zathura-raise.service`. Save it in `~/.config/systemd/user`, start it by `systemctl --user start zathura-raise.service`, enable it by `systemctl --user enable zathura-raise.service`, and forget about it.

`~/.config/systemd/user/zathura-raise.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Raise Zathura window on Synctex forward search

[Service]
ExecStart=%h/bin/zathura-raise.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```